# What is the difference between a Rust function with no argument and a function with one unused argument?

Tags: function, arguments, rust

What's the difference between making a function like this:

```
fn add(_: i32) -> i32 {
    10 + 25
}
```

And this one:

```
fn add() -> i32 {
    10 + 25
}
```

I realize that the first function requires an argument when being called, even though it's not used, so I reckon that the second version should okay in that case.

Is there any reason why I'm allowed to use the first version? I'm seeing this in the example of Iron when implementing a handler to a certain route. I'm confused as to why it has to be that way when supplying an empty argument should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function signature is a contract between the caller and the callee:

- it allows the caller to ensure that the arguments it passes are the one specified by the contract
- it allows the callee to be assured that the arguments it received are the one specified by the contract

And, maybe more importantly, it enforces **an encapsulation boundary**: the caller has no idea which arguments are read or modified by the callee, all it knows is what the contract requires.

This encapsulation is the driving factor here. The API was designed because *some* clients may make use of this value, so it is passed around. Whether a *particular* client uses it or not, is an **implementation detail** of the client, and the caller does not (and should not) care.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: a function with zero arguments has a different API and ABI from a function with one argument.

Long answer:

The Iron handler expects a function with one argument. If you were able to pass a function with no arguments, how would Iron know about that? It's specifying that there should be one argument, so that's the API requirement. The fact that you throw away the argument changes nothing, Iron will still pass that one argument to the function.

If you would (unsafely) pass a function that has zero arguments, then Iron will still pass that one argument, but the function's code doesn't expect an argument and you thus would have introduced undefined behaviour.

That said, Iron could supply some helper trait magic that allows you to pass zero argument functions, but all that would do is introduce a second layer that you don't see:

```
fn short_add() -> i32 {
    add(42) // or another dummy value
}
```

Comment: Another aspect to consider: if you could call a function with "too many" arguments without complaint, how would you ever know some of the arguments you *meant* to pass were just being discarded?

Answer (score 1):

Functions with different signatures are not interchangeable, as the ABI is different.

While you might think it doesn't make a difference if you're ignoring the parameter, you can't rely on that; and there are certainly cases where it does matter.  For example, anything with a destructor would expect the called function to destroy the parameter before returning.

One of Rust's strengths is its strong type system which disallows incorrect uses like this by default (similarly integer conversions, etc.); and in this particular case it's pretty easy to add the unnamed/unused parameter so not really significantly inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, you can pass function pointers and closures around, but functions with different arguments and returns have different types.

Example:

```
fn test_no_args(f0: fn() -> i32) {
    println!("{}", f0())
} 

fn test_1_arg(f1: fn(i32) -> i32) {
    println!("{}", f1(3))
}

fn main() {
    // test function with no args
    fn t0() -> i32 {
        42
    }

    // test func with 1 arg
    // we're discarding the arg
    // but we need this signature to call test_1_arg
    fn t1(_: i32) -> i32 {
        3
    }

    test_no_args(t0);
    test_1_arg(t1);
    // test_no_args(t1); doesn't compile, test_no_args expects a fn() -> i32
}
```

Note how `test_1_arg` expects a `fn(i32)-> i32`, but we want to feed it our t1 function that does not really need the input.

Answer (score -1):

The first function means I have function `add` but the function itself says I don't care what it is.

but the second one means I don't need any parameters. they are not compatible with each other.

The iron framework need a function it will feed a argument to it. The framework didn't care you use the parameter or not.